# Mopabarcode issue in generating multiple barcode images in symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, zend-framework2

I am trying to generate multiple barcode image files in symfony by looping.
Here loop start......

```
$barcodeService = $this->container->get('mopa_barcode.barcode_service');
$filename = $barcode . ".png";
$barcodeService->saveAs('code128', $barcode, $filename);
```

loop end here.....

for one item its working fine but when trying it in looping it giving me an exception as

> ErrorException: Warning: imagesy(): 57 is not a valid Image resource in `/vendor/Zend/library/Zend/Barcode/Renderer/Image.php` line 267

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As j0k suggested to update ZF, you would need to do the same.

I created the issue at [MopaBarcodeBundle Issue List](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBarcodeBundle/issues/9). I updated my ZF version to latest release and solved the problem. I tried to find out the problem. It was related to use of the registry (singleton) pattern for the management of objects.

And please have a look at [Mopa Compatible code](https://github.com/calumbrodie/zend-barcode/tree/mopa_compatible)

Good Luck

Comment: Basically, what I said ... Anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're not the only one with this problem: https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBarcodeBundle/issues/9

As people suggest, try to upgrade your ZF2 if you are not using the last one. And/or [check the forked version of the Bundle](https://github.com/calumbrodie/zend-barcode/tree/mopa_compatible) from calumbrodie.